# John's Circular Table (Combinatorics)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $14$ seats at John's circular table. John places $7$ oranges and $7$ tangerines at random at the $14$ seats. He picks a random pair of oranges. What is the probability they are NOT "sitting" next to each other?

I tried using complementary counting (e.g trying to find the probability that they are sitting next to each other), but I got nowhere. I thought that the only way this would be true is if the oranges and tangerines alternated. Can someone guide me through the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Every pair of seats is equally likely to occur (as the fruits were also placed randomly).

There are $14$ pairs of adjacent seats and $\binom{14}{2}=\frac{14\times 13}{2}$.

Hence the probability they sit together is $\frac{2}{13}$ and the probability they don't is $\frac{11}{13}$

Comment: @ Jorge Fernandez: The question is not about two randomly chosen seats being apart, but that of two randomly chosen $oranges$ being apart.

Answer (score 1):

I will first work through a very small example, say $3$ each of oranges and tangerines.

There are only $4$ distinct **rings** under rotational invariance, viz.

$OOOTTT|(O):$ Two ways to choose adjacent oranges
$OOTOTT|(O):$ One way to choose adjacent oranges
$OOTTOT|(O):$ One way to choose adjacent oranges
$OTOTOT|(O):$ Zero ways to choose adjacent oranges

Thus P(adjacent) $= \dfrac4{12}=\dfrac13,\;$ and P(apart) = $\dfrac23$

whereas Jorge's approach would yield $\dfrac25$ and $\dfrac35$ respectively.

I have worked out for the $7$ each case, and get an answer of $\dfrac{243}{287}, \approx 0.8467$ apart.

Let me explain the approach and notation, we focus on placement of oranges.

$5-2-0-0-0-0-0-$ means that slot number $1$ has $5$ oranges, and another slot has $2$ oranges, with $\binom61$ choices for placing it , so $6$ *rings*, and $4+1 = 5$ ways for choosing adjacent oranges

Here is the working, you definitely need to countercheck the arithmetic computations !

$7-0-0-0-0-0-0-:\quad 1\cdot6 = 6\;\;(1 \; ring,\; 6\;adjacent)$
$6-1-0-0-0-0-0-:\quad \binom61\cdot5 = 30$
$5-2-0-0-0-0-0-:\quad 6\cdot5 = 30$
$5-1-1-0-0-0-0-:\quad \binom62\cdot4 = 60$
$4-3-0-0-0-0-0-:\quad 6\cdot5 = 30$
$4-2-1-0-0-0-0-:\quad 15\cdot4 = 60$
$4-1-2-0-0-0-0-:\quad 15\cdot4 = 60$
$4-1-1-1-0-0-0-:\quad \binom63\cdot3 = 60$
$3-3-1-0-0-0-0-:\quad 15\cdot4 = 60$
$3-2-2-0-0-0-0-:\quad 15\cdot4 = 60$
$3-2-1-1-0-0-0-:\quad 20\cdot3 = 60$
$3-1-2-1-0-0-0-:\quad 20\cdot3 = 60$
$3-1-1-2-0-0-0-:\quad 20\cdot3 = 60$
$3-1-1-1-1-0-0-:\quad \binom64\cdot2 = 30$
$2-2-2-1-0-0-0-:\quad 20\cdot3 = 60$
$2-2-1-1-1-0-0-:\quad 15\cdot2 = 30$
$2-1-2-1-1-0-0-:\quad 15\cdot2 = 30$
$2-1-1-1-1-1-0-:\quad \binom65\cdot1 = 6$
$1-1-1-1-1-1-1-:\quad \binom66\cdot 0 = 0$

Number of rings $= 246$, number of adjacent orange pairs $= 792$

P(two are adjacent) $=\dfrac{792}{246\cdot\binom72} = \dfrac{44}{287}$

and finally, P(two are apart) $= \dfrac{243}{287}, \approx 0.8467$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $\frac{11}{13}$ as Jorge says. However it is perhaps not obvious that the probability two randomly selected *oranges* are next to each other is the same as the probability that two randomly selected *seats* are next to each other. One way to see this is to choose your two oranges first, mark them, then distribute the fruit at random one by one, starting with the two marked oranges.

Comment: Please see my answer, specially the example with 3 oranges and 3 tangerines.

Comment: @trueblueanil your answer is not correct, because you can't just ignore rotations. There are only two ways to place the fruit to give a rotation of OTOTOT (that way or TOTOTO), whereas there are six rotations of each of the other patterns (eg OOOTTT, OOTTTO, OTTTOO, TTTOOO, TTOOOT, TOOOTT). So each of the other patterns is three times as likely as the last pattern,. Factoring this in means you get $12$ successes out of $30$, or $2/5$.

Comment: I am a  bit confused. Aren't  4 possible $necklaces$ formed from 3 beads each of two colors supposed to be equi-probable ?

Comment: My approach is not incorrect. I have taken the problem to be one of a $necklace$ that can't be flipped. Jorge's answer, and your comments amount to taking $numbered$ seats. The normal practice for circular arrangements is to treat seats as unnumbered unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @trueblueanil What do you mean? The person chooses $7$ spots at random from the $14$ spots. Each subset is equally likely.

Comment: @JorgeFernández: There was a problem that generated quite a bit of controversy. " Kevin has four red marbles and eight blue marbles. He arranges these twelve marbles randomly, in a ring. Determine the probability that no two red marbles are adjacent." Two contending answers were 7/33 and 10/43 respectively. ...continued

Comment: @JorgeFernández: The difference was that the first answer assumed 12 labelled points, whereas the second treated is as a  "fixed necklace" http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Necklace.html, which is what I have done. The question and the dispute over it can be seen at https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101022213106AAQnHwO.

Comment: @JorgeFernández: And as I have mentioned in an earlier comment, in circular arrangements, the normal practice is to take positions/seats as unlabelled/unnumbered unless explicitly specified otherwise.

Comment: I have never seen that practice in a probability question of this sort. I have only seen it in enumeration problems. I will +1 your answer in case that is the desired interpretation but I don't think it is.